# How small can an external angle of a circumference be if made of tangents?

Tags: geometry, circles, analytic-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Lets imagine the angle ABC where the lines AB and CB are tangents to a circumference which center is C. Lets assume that the points where the line AB touches the circumference is P and the point where CB touches the circumference is V; the point where these lines cross is B. If a line is drawn from P to V can it pass through C? I'm assuming it can't, so which is the shortest (whole) distance between C and the line PV that could exist and how does that translate to the size of the angle (or its distance from the center) or in other words which is the smallest angle two tangents can make?

Comment: CB is tangent to the circle and C is the center?

Comment: A sketch would help.

Answer (score 0):

I can not add a comment but it is clear that the statements are contradicting. C can not be a center and at the same time have a tangent running through it.
You need to edit the question.
In any case: A line through the touching points of tangents originating at any point external to the circumference (circle?) could not go through a center - if the line goes through the center it means that the two lines are parallel, thus not originating from an external point.